# get account profile after logging in?

Tags: meteor

is it possible to get the user profile pic after the user has signedup and then signed in using meteor accounts. I tried querying

```
Meteor.user().services.google
or 
Meteor.user().services.facebook
```

but I `Meteor.user().services` comes out as undefined. So I'm not quite sure how to access the profile pic.

Note I don't want to rewrite the signup process and Accounts.onCreateUser it would be much easier to simply add in user details after a user logs in.

Comment: Why not fill in this missing data inside a `Accounts.onLogin` hook?

Comment: sure that sounds reasonable, but I still don't know how to access the profile pics, when user.services is returning undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options but the best would be to write `Accounts.onLogin` because there is a security reason you can't access it with `Meteor.user().services`.

The stuff inside Meteor.user().services is sensitive, it contains the OAuth keys, your Meteor access tokens and your password hashes, this is why its blocked from access to the client. Its a very short CSF attack to stealing your account (and possibly get access to your facebook, google+, twitter, etc)

You can make it 'open'

**Server side code**

```
Meteor.publish("userdata", function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
});
```

**Client side code**

```
Meteor.subscribe("userdata")
```

---

### More Secure Way

The more secure way would be to create the onLogin/onCreate callback, grab their profile picture url/other profile data and put it in `profile` and **not have** any publish functions like the one above

In your onLogin callback

```
var avatar = .. get your avatar url for whatever service you're using


//Assuming you've called the onLogin callback parameter 'info'
Meteor.users.update({_id: info.user._id}, {$set:{'profile.avatar':avatar}});
```

Then you can just do this when you need their profile pic

```
<img src="{{currentUser.profile.avatar}}"/>
```

This way you could do the same for the other data too! And standardize it in a way that works accross multiple services (facebook, google+, twitter, etc)